# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object' ts(2339) for React and Ionic project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

So I am building a React + Ionic + Typescript project. I am using the React hooks to set an array of objects. I then map through that array of objects and am trying to access a certain key in that object but it is saying that it doesn't exist (challenge.name).

```
const FindChallenges: React.FC = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const [searchedChallenge, setSearchedChallenge] = useState<string>(); // what user searched.
  const [allChallenges, setAllChallenges] = useState<Array<Object>>([]); // the challenges that match search.
  // const [test, setTest] = useState<Array<Object>>([{1:"test"}, {2: "hello"}, {3: "world"}]);

  // Only works for web right now.
  // Will need to set up PORT forwarding for ios/android.
  const API_URL = "http://localhost:3001"; 

  useEffect(() => {
    // if (!isAuthenticated) return;
    fetch(API_URL + "/api/getAllChallenges", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(res => {
        let results = [];
        for (let key in res) {
          results.push(res[key])
        }
        setAllChallenges(results);
        
      })
  }, []);

  if (!isAuthenticated) return (<PageLock />);




  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("FORM SUBMITTED");
    // setSearchedChallenge("");
  }




  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle className="ion-text-center">Find a Challenge</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        {/* <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">Find ChallengesTab</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader> */}
        <IonCard>
          {/* <IonItem>
            <IonLabel className="ion-text-center" id="profileLabel">Your Challenges</IonLabel>
          </IonItem> */}
          <IonCardContent id="ionCardContent">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <IonInput clear-input="true" id="search-challenge-input" value={searchedChallenge} placeholder="Enter Input" onIonChange={e => setSearchedChallenge(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
              <IonButton expand="block" type="submit" className="ion-margin-top">
                Search
              </IonButton>
            </form>
          </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
        <br></br>
        {console.log(allChallenges)}
        <IonCard>
          
          {allChallenges.map(challenge => (
            // <IonItem href="#" className="ion-activated">
            //   <IonLabel>{challenge}</IonLabel>
            // </IonItem>
            <div>
              <>{console.log(challenge)}</>
              <>{console.log(challenge.name)}</>
              {/* <>{challenge.key}</> */}
            </div>
          ))}
          

          
        </IonCard>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

This is how the object is structured (when you console.log(challenges) in the map function), and it clearly has the "name" key, so why is it coming up as unknown??
[image: Object]

Comment: One of the whole points of using TypeScript is to declare your types instead of using `any` or `Object`. `Object` does *not* have a `name` property. Declare your type correctly and use it in place of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

before the allchallenges state set in the useEffect it's empty and it doesn't have any name in it you can do two things first:

```
const [allChallenges, setAllChallenges] = useState<Array<Object>>([{name:"", key:0}]);
```

and the second one you can set a boolean state after fetch like isOK and then turn it true after you got the result and use it like this:

```
  const [isOK , SetIsOK] = useState(false);

    {isOK && allChallenges.map(challenge => (
                // <IonItem href="#" className="ion-activated">
                //   <IonLabel>{challenge}</IonLabel>
                // </IonItem>
                <div>
                  <>{console.log(challenge)}</>
                  <>{console.log(challenge.name)}</>
                  {/* <>{challenge.key}</> */}
                </div>
              ))}
```

Comment: Hmm it is still coming up as "property 'name' does not exist on type object" for the second console log

Comment: Try setAllChallenges(res) after you get the res i think you save it wrong

Comment: Nope doesn't do anything. Not sure why the error is still coming up. There definitely is a 'name' key in the object.

Comment: console.log the result array before setAllChallenges maybe you found out something

Comment: It is perfectly fine. Before I set challenges and also after I set challenges. But when I try mapping through the array, it says it doesn't have that property.

Comment: did you do the thing that i said? const [allChallenges, setAllChallenges] = useState<Array<Object>>([{name:"", key:0}]);  because before the result goes to the state its empty and doesn't have any name in it if you did this and nothing happend i'm 100% sure that its your result array's problem

Answer (score -1):

TO fix this, all I had to do was change my `useState` type for the allChallenges. I changed it from `<Array<Object>>` to `<Array<any>>` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: One of the whole points of using TypeScript is to declare your types instead of using `any` or `Object`. `Object` does not have a name property. Declare your type correctly and use it in place of `Object`.

Comment: well what would the type be??? Because it is an Object that contains multiple types in it? And clearly Object as the type does not work...

Comment: The type would be whatever you decide the type is, either because you've created to represent your data or reflect the data coming back from an API. For example, `type Data = { createdBy: string, description: string, id: number };`. Otherwise, you are not using the strengths of TypeScript.